# Default formule in text field

Tags: formula, formula-field

I am new to salesforce. I have two custom objects. One is Vob and other is Legal.

I have a text field on Vob object having name as Rx OUT DED and I have created another text field on Legal object. I want the value of Rx OUT DED of Vob to be displayed on Rx OUT DED of legal.

I am trying to use the default formulae on Rx OUT DED of legal field as VOB__r.Rx_OUT_DED__c but I am getting the error as Error: Field VOB__r does not exist. Check spelling.

Should I create a formula field for Rx OUT DED and add this formulae or am I doing something wrong.

Comment: can you explain any relationship exists between two objects.@kunal gupta

Comment: If `Legal__c` is a child of `Vob__c` then the formula field (assuming you took the defaults for the relationship name) on `Legal__c.Rx_Out_ded__c=vob__r.rx_out_ded__c`  Legal__c` is a parent of `Vob__c` you can't use formulas as which VOB__c would be the one to use.